# get payer infos after successful payment on paypal

Tags: paypal

I created a paypal checkout. after successful purchase. is there a way to get the client's info from paypal?
ex.
**Name
Address
County
Town
Phone number
etc.**

I only have a checkout button. then they will automatically redirected to paypal
but then I need to save the client's info to my database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into the Instant Payment Notification option?  I've used this with great success in the past, after the customer has placed the order PayPal will send a notification script that you specify which contains all the transaction details - including the customer information.

Link: https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Comment: Including phone number? 
can you specify a sample Thank you.

Comment: I added a link to PayPal's IPN section.

Comment: can you check this url.
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

Comment: // assign posted variables to local variables

Comment: The site should list different integrations, as well as examples using code in the most popular languages.